# Combine two tables using the row data of table 2 as column header

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

How can I combine two tables using the row data of table 2 as column header?

table 1:

| id | email | firstname | middlename | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2901 | john@io.com | john | michael | smith |

table 2:

| id | questionId | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2901 | 1 | Toronto |
| 2901 | 2 | Canada |
| 2901 | 3 | 9991118721 |

Final result should be table 1 headers plus questionId data as header, then using table 1 data and table 2 answer data as rows:

| id | email | firstname | middlename | lastname | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2901 | john@io.com | john | michael | smith | Toronto | Canada | 9991118721 |

Comment: Have a look at the PIVOT/UNPIVOT functions

Comment: Only with Dynamic SQL if you need the column names to be the value of the question id dynamically. I would personally suggest you perhaps rethink about this is you *really* "need" this. If you do *really* "need" this, then see [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404348/2029983). If you don't understand the solution, then I also suggest rethinking; dynamic SQL isn't something you should be using unless you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
select t1.id, t1.email, t1.firstname, t1.middlename, t1.lastname,
       max(case when t2.questionId=1 then t2.answer else null end) 1,
       max(case when t2.questionId=2 then t2.answer else null end) 2,
       max(case when t2.questionId=3 then t2.answer else null end) 3
from table1 t1
     join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.email, t1.firstname, t1.middlename, t1.lastname;
```